# Retrieving information from an array

Tags: php, json

hey im pretty new to php so if ive asked a stupid question please forgive me. ive reasearch this topic for hours and i cant seem to find something that works.

i need to extracted information from an array. the array is located on this url

http://api.wunderground.com/api/5e8af95dbdebbd73/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/UK/England.json

if you search that you can see all the informtion of many Eng/Uk towns and cities

im trying to make it so that a user can input their curent location and they information they draw out is the same as whatever is the array of the link above.

this is the code so far

```
 <h3> Weather Data </h3>

<form method= "POST" action="about.php">

<input type="text" name="location" value = "location"/>

</form>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $.ajax({

  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/5e8af95dbdebbd73/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/UK/England.json",

 dataType : "jsonp",

  success : function(parsed_json) {

  var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];

  var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];


    alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);

  }
  });
});
```

Comment: BTW there is a button in the form i just forgot to add it

Comment: input is a city name? and you want to print the associated details when click button?

Comment: yeah thats right but i want them in the alert if that possible ?

Comment: if not i could just echo them out either

Comment: I have cjhecked this in my local,,the data you are checking with that URL contains large list..browser is hanging..so you need to found some other way...Any api given by that city if you give city name as a param in url ?

Comment: it is possible ............

Comment: So please give me the API URL with sending city param..I will provide you a sample to get data.